# Insert Data using models with ASP.NET Core and EF Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have question in regarding with my code,

My primary goal here is to insert data which is from a model which in that model I set multiple models to grab data.  Here is my code in my **Model**:

```
public class ModelLoan
{
    public SelectList employees { get; set; }
    public SelectList collectors { get; set; }
    public SelectList loanTypes { get; set; }
    public SelectList loanStatus { get; set; }
    public SelectList loanFrequency { get; set; }
    public LoanContract loanContract { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //For Employees List
        var lstEmployee = _Context.Employee.OrderBy(e => e.Fname + ' ' + e.Lname).Select(x => new { Id = x.EmployeeId, Value = x.Fname + ' ' + x.Lname });
        //For Collectors List
        var lstCollector = _Context.Collectors.OrderBy(c => c.CollectorName).Select(x => new { Id = x.CollectorId, Value = x.CollectorName});
        //For Loan Type List
        var lstLoanType = _Context.LoanType.OrderBy(lt => lt.Description).Select(x => new { Id = x.LoanTypeId, Value = x.Description });
        //For Loan Status List
        var lstLoanStatus = _Context.LoanStatus.OrderBy(ls => ls.StatusName).Select(x => new { Id = x.LoanStatusId, Value = x.StatusName });
        //For Loan Frequency List
        var lstLoanFrequency = _Context.LoanFrequency.OrderBy(lf => lf.LoanFrequencyId).Select(x => new { Id = x.LoanFrequencyId, Value = x.Description });

        var myList = new ModelLoan();
        myList.employees = new SelectList(lstEmployee, "Id", "Value");
        myList.collectors = new SelectList(lstCollector, "Id", "Value");
        myList.loanTypes = new SelectList(lstLoanType, "Id", "Value");
        myList.loanStatus = new SelectList(lstLoanStatus, "Id", "Value", 1003);
        myList.loanFrequency = new SelectList(lstLoanFrequency, "Id", "Value", 2);

        //Set Default
        return View(myList);
    }
```

Now from this I put those data on a `SelectList` method which it is easy for me to view through using `<select>` tag.  But the problem is I don't know how to extract the `value` of it.

Now here is my **View:**

```html
@model prjPEMCOLoan.Models.ModelLoan

 

<form asp-controller="Loan" asp-action="SaveLoanContract" role="form" method="post" style="padding-top: 2em;">
    <h2>Loan Application</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Employee</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="lc.loanContract.EmployeeId"  asp-items="@Model.employees"></select>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Select the specific employee. If employee name is not on the list then you register the employee <a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index">here</a>.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Collector</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="lc.loanContract.CollectorId" asp-items="@Model.collectors"></select>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Collector will be the one to check your loan status in this system.  He/She will be the responsible for accepting/rejecting your loan applied.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Loan Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="lc.loanContract.LoanTypeId" asp-items="@Model.loanTypes"></select>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Choose your desired loan type you want to apply.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Status</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="lc.loanContract.LoanStatusId" asp-items="@Model.loanStatus" disabled></select>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Upon registration to this loan you are set to pending status as default to check your loan by the collectors.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Status</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="lc.loanContract.LoanFrequencyId" asp-items="@Model.loanFrequency" disabled></select>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Upon registration to this loan you are set to a <b>Biweekly</b> because your payroll mostly computed and deducted every Biweekly day of the month.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Date Applied: </label><span> </span>
            <input disabled type="date" name="lc.loanContract.LoanDateStart" id="dpDateNow" class="form-control" /><br />
            <small class="form-text text-muted">This is the date you applied.</small>
            <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Date Approved: </label><span> </span>
            <input type="date" id="dpDateApproved" name="lc.loanContract.LoanDateEnd" class="form-control" /><br />
            <small class="form-text text-muted">This is the date where your loan will be approved.</small>
            <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Due Date: </label>
            <input type="date" id="dpDateDue" name="lc.loanContract.LoanPaymentDue" class="form-control" /><br />
            <small class="form-text text-muted">Date where you expected to pay them all.</small>
            <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
        </div>
    </div><br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Loan Amount</label>
        <input required placeholder="Enter Amount (must be number)" name="lc.loanContract.LoanAmount" class="form-control" type="number"/>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Input the amount you want to loan.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control" style="height: 100%">
        <label>Terms and Condition</label><br />
        <input required type="checkbox" name="lc.loanContract.isAcceptTac"/>
        <small class="form-text text-muted"><b>I Agree, Read and Accept the terms terms and condition. </b><br />
            PEMCO Loan is an online peer to peer loans community that connects people with money to lend to people who need to borrow money. Lending Hub works in a controlled and regulated environment that allows members to interact anonymously (from each other). To make sure that a secure and safe community is maintained we have developed these terms and conditions of use to assist all members. These terms and conditions explain what you can expect from us, what we expect from you, and what members can expect from each other and these terms and conditions will apply to you whenever you browse, transact or interact on the site.
        </small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div><br />
    <div class="form-control-static">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Apply</b></button>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Now everything is on set on the view the only thing I have problem right now is inserting data from the `ModelLoan.loanContract` which I defined here in my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SaveLoanContract(ModelLoan lc)
    { 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await _Context.LoanContract.AddAsync(lc.loanContract);
            await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(lc.loanContract);
    }
```

What suppose to be the problem on my code?  I miss a little thing but I don't know where.  Can you guys help me with this? Thanks!

**Update:**
This is exception happens when I the `asp-action = "SaveLoanContract"` since it is associated with the index itself.

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'SaveLoanContract' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>    /Views/Loan/SaveLoanContract.cshtml
>    /Views/Shared/SaveLoanContract.cshtml

However when I changed the `asp-action = "Index"`

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'PEMCOLoan.DAL.Entities.Models.LoanContract', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'prjPEMCOLoan.Models.ModelLoan'.

Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Can you provide exception detail ? maybe ModelLoan has a missing attribute [FromBody], Have you checked lc is a valid instance and lc.loanContract has values?

Comment: Hi, the question is updated.  You may check right now.

Comment: Please check routes for methods in controller, It seems like there is a trouble with route table

Comment: @H. Herzl hmp... okay but can you provide me a code? sorry I'm still studying asp.net core right now.. not so familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.NET Core you have the new tag `asp-for`. Change your view to:

```
@model prjPEMCOLoan.Models.ModelLoan

<form asp-controller="Loan" asp-action="SaveLoanContract" role="form" method="post" style="padding-top: 2em;">
<h2>Loan Application</h2>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Employee</label>
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="loanContract.EmployeeId" asp-items="@Model.employees"></select>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Select the specific employee. If employee name is not on the list then you register the employee <a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index">here</a>.</small>
    <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Collector</label>
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="loanContract.CollectorId" asp-items="@Model.collectors"></select>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Collector will be the one to check your loan status in this system.  He/She will be the responsible for accepting/rejecting your loan applied.</small>
    <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Loan Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="loanContract.LoanTypeId" asp-items="@Model.loanTypes"></select>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Choose your desired loan type you want to apply.</small>
    <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Status</label>
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="loanContract.LoanStatusId" asp-items="@Model.loanStatus" disabled></select>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Upon registration to this loan you are set to pending status as default to check your loan by the collectors.</small>
    <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Status</label>
    <select class="form-control" asp-for="loanContract.LoanFrequencyId" asp-items="@Model.loanFrequency" disabled></select>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Upon registration to this loan you are set to a <b>Biweekly</b> because your payroll mostly computed and deducted every Biweekly day of the month.</small>
    <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Date Applied: </label><span> </span>
        <input disabled type="date" asp-for="loanContract.LoanDateStart" id="dpDateNow" class="form-control" /><br />
        <small class="form-text text-muted">This is the date you applied.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Date Approved: </label><span> </span>
        <input type="date" id="dpDateApproved" asp-for="loanContract.LoanDateEnd" class="form-control" /><br />
        <small class="form-text text-muted">This is the date where your loan will be approved.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label> Due Date: </label>
        <input type="date" id="dpDateDue" asp-for="loanContract.LoanPaymentDue" class="form-control" /><br />
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Date where you expected to pay them all.</small>
        <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
    </div>
</div><br />
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Loan Amount</label>
    <input required placeholder="Enter Amount (must be number)" asp-for="loanContract.LoanAmount" class="form-control" type="number"/>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Input the amount you want to loan.</small>
    <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-control" style="height: 100%">
    <label>Terms and Condition</label><br />
    <input required type="checkbox" asp-for="loanContract.isAcceptTac"/>
    <small class="form-text text-muted"><b>I Agree, Read and Accept the terms terms and condition. </b><br />
        PEMCO Loan is an online peer to peer loans community that connects people with money to lend to people who need to borrow money. Lending Hub works in a controlled and regulated environment that allows members to interact anonymously (from each other). To make sure that a secure and safe community is maintained we have developed these terms and conditions of use to assist all members. These terms and conditions explain what you can expect from us, what we expect from you, and what members can expect from each other and these terms and conditions will apply to you whenever you browse, transact or interact on the site.
    </small>
    <span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>
</div><br />
<div class="form-control-static">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Apply</b></button>
</div>
```

Your controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveLoanContract(ModelLoan lc)
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await _Context.LoanContract.AddAsync(lc.loanContract);
        await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // Get the list data again and populate the entire model
    lc.employees = new SelectList(lstEmployee, "Id", "Value");
    lc.collectors = new SelectList(lstCollector, "Id", "Value");
    // and so on

    return View("Index", lc); // also it may be required to specify the full path for the view like ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
}
```

PS: This `<span asp-validation-summary="All"></span>` part of the code does not require to be on each input. You can place once before the inputs.